# Fail to format disk, missing mkfs file. [mkfs: failed to execute mkfs.* : No such file or directory]

Tags: debian, xfs, mkfs

While working on a fresh install of debian on GCP, I am trying to format a disk to `xfs`.

```
sudo mkfs -t xfs -n ftype=1 /dev/sdb -f
```

which gives me this error:

```
mkfs: failed to execute mkfs.xfs: No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts? I guess I need to install something but the error does not make it clear what to install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was indeed missing `xfsprogs`, which upon installing did solve my issue.

So, first install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install xfsprogs
```

then:

```
sudo mkfs -t xfs -n ftype=1 /dev/sdb -f
```